# Using FTP to delete files from remote server:

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

I am using this to remove file from remote server

```
sshpass -p $SERVER_PASSWORD ssh $SERVER_IP 'find '$SERVER_PATH_TO_REMOVE_BACKUP' -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;'
```

I want to use ftp account to delete from remote server. I am using this-

```
ncftp -u"ftpuser" -p"ftppwd" serverIp <<EOF
find '/back/' -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
EOF
```

But unable to delete. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftp.html) client supports a find command.

```
ncftp  -uuser -ppassword box.tld <<EOF                        
find /home/iain -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -exec echo {} \;
EOF

NcFTP 3.2.5 (Feb 02, 2011) by Mike Gleason (http://www.NcFTP.com/contact/).
Connecting to 192.168.254.188...
(vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Logging in...
Login successful.
Logged in to box.tld.
find: no such command. <----
```

See. you even get a nice error message to tell you that.

Comment: Any Alternate solution ?

Comment: @HimanshuMatta: Not via ftp, it just doesn't have that kind of functionality.